# How to hide background while throbber/loading is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax throbber in my pages.

Throbber is working fine.However,I want to hide background while throbber is in process.

Here are the examples of what am looking for??

https://drupal.org/files/ajax-block-working.png
https://drupal.org/files/sexy-throbber.png

Comment: Hide what background?

Comment: screen/page behind the loading

Answer (score 1):

You should have an div with following css code:

```
.overlay{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position:fixed;
z-index:99999;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

then in html wrote this:

```
<div class="overlay" id="ovly"> </div>
```

and at last in script wrote this :

```
//when your ajax is start loading
$("#ovly").show();
```

and remember that in your css there should not be any z-index more than 99999 excepts the loading img property